# YALV (yet another loop vectorization)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I can write some code along these lines, to compute, for different frequencies, a harmonic function that respect given initial conditions.

```
from numpy import *
...
for i in range(n_freqs):
    # A, B so that X(t) = A cos(w t) + B sin(w t)
    # and X(t0) = x, dX/dt(t0) = v
    w = ws[i] # use a frequency
    solver = array(((+cos(w*t0), -sin(w*t0)),
                    (+sin(w*t0), +cos(w*t0)))) 
    AB = solver @ array((x[i], v[i]/w)) # and store somewhere the result
```

but I would like to write something more like

```
Solver = array(((+cos(ws*t0), -sin(ws*t0)),
                (+sin(ws*t0), +cos(ws*t0))))
AB = Solver @ vstack((x,v/ws)
```

M(not)WE

```
from numpy import *

ws = array((1., 2., 3., 4.))
x = array((3., 6., 2., 1.))
v = x
t0 = 10.0
Solver = array(((+cos(ws*t0), -sin(ws*t0)),
                (+sin(ws*t0), +cos(ws*t0))))
AB = Solver @ vstack((x,v/ws)
```

that gives me the following trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shapes (2,2,4) and (2,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 2) != 2 (dim 0)
```

while

```
(Solver @ vstack((x,v/ws).T).shape # -> (2, 2, 2)
```

when I want a `(2, 4)` (or `(4,2)`, I'm not too choosy) shape...

Is it possible to write a loop less expression that computes at once the coefficients of the different trigonometric functions?

Comment: There's a little shape ambiguity here, 2*2=4.  If the example used (5,) arrays it would be clearer.

Comment: Aside: doing `from numpy import *` is just going to get you in trouble.  Using `np.whatever` is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w` is `(n,)`, so `cos(w*t0)` has that shape too.  `Solver` is laid out as (2,2), but with (n,) elements so it is (2,2,n).  You are 'dotting' with a (2,n).  But on which dimension, the `n` or one of `2`?

```
solver(ws[i]) @ array((x[i], v[i]/ws[i]))
```

indicates that you want the last dimension to 'go along for the ride', and to dot on the last 2 of `Solver`.  In Einsum notation:

```
np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik', Solver, arr)

In [99]: Solver = np.array(((np.cos(wst),-np.sin(wst)),(np.sin(wst),np.cos(wst))))

In [101]: b = np.vstack((x,v/ws))
In [102]: b.shape
Out[102]: (2, 4)
In [103]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     print(Solver[:,:,i]@b[:,i])
     ...:     
[-0.88515125 -4.14927792]
[-0.29034338  6.70191769]
[ 0.96719065 -1.87322895]
[-0.85321635  0.57837865]
In [104]: np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',Solver,b)
Out[104]: 
array([[-0.88515125, -0.29034338,  0.96719065, -0.85321635],
       [-4.14927792,  6.70191769, -1.87322895,  0.57837865]])
```

This isn't an easy case for `@` because that assumes the arrays are stacked on the first dimension.  e.g `Solver` should be `(n,2,2)`, and `b` (n,2,1)`

```
In [106]: Solver.transpose(2,0,1)@(b.T[...,None])
Out[106]: 
array([[[-0.88515125],
        [-4.14927792]],

       [[-0.29034338],
        [ 6.70191769]],

       [[ 0.96719065],
        [-1.87322895]],

       [[-0.85321635],
        [ 0.57837865]]])
In [107]: _.shape   # need to squeeze out the last dim
Out[107]: (4, 2, 1)
```

---

If my deduction is right that your 'dot' dimension is size 2, iterating on that dimension will be nearly as fast, especially for large n:

```
res = np.zeros((2,n))
for i in range(2):
    res += Solver[:,i,:] * b[i,:]
```

Comment: In the end I'm going to use `np.einsum('ijk,jk->jk', Solver, arr)`.  The dot-product approach is way too complicated, isn't it? `einsum` is powerful but I haven't still wrapped my head around it... I should try harder... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Interpretation #1

Assumption : We are looking to get `Solver @ b[0]`, `Solver @ b[1]` and so on, i.e. iterating against the first axis of `Solver` and `b` and using the `@` operator.

Given : `b = np.vstack((x,v/ws))`, we could use `einsum` or `matmul/@` or `tensordot/dot`.

**Approach #1 :** With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',Solver, b).reshape(-1,2)
```

**Approach #2 :** With [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
np.matmul(Solver, b.T).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,2)
```

Now `@` operator, I believe, being a replacement for `np.matmul` on Python 3.5, we simply need to replace : `np.matmul(Solver, b.T)` with `Solver @ b.T`.

**Approach #3 :** With [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(b, Solver, axes=((-1),(-1))).reshape(-1,2)
```

**Approach #4 :** We can also use the more popular [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) with some reshaping before feeding it to the function, like so -

```
b.dot(Solver.reshape(4,-1).T).reshape(-1,2)
```

Sample run -

1) Setup inputs :

```
In [7]: ws = np.array((1., 2., 3., 4.))
   ...: x = np.array((3., 6., 2., 1.))
   ...: v = x
   ...: t0 = 10.0
   ...: Solver = np.array(((+np.cos(ws*t0), -np.sin(ws*t0)), \
   ...:                     (np.sin(ws*t0), +np.cos(ws*t0))))
    ...: b = np.vstack((x,v/ws))
    ...:
```

2) Get output iteratively :

```
In [8]: Solver @ b[0]
Out[8]: 
array([[-0.42715738, -2.61465808],
       [ 2.61465808, -0.42715738]])

In [9]: Solver @ b[1]
Out[9]: 
array([[-1.35686862, -0.63436296],
       [ 0.63436296, -1.35686862]])
```

3) Use `einsum` and verify outputs :

```
In [10]: np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',Solver, b).reshape(-1,2)
Out[10]: 
array([[-0.42715738, -2.61465808],
       [ 2.61465808, -0.42715738],
       [-1.35686862, -0.63436296],
       [ 0.63436296, -1.35686862]])
```

4) Use `matmul` and verify outputs :

```
In [11]: np.matmul(Solver, b.T).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,2)
Out[11]: 
array([[-0.42715738, -2.61465808],
       [ 2.61465808, -0.42715738],
       [-1.35686862, -0.63436296],
       [ 0.63436296, -1.35686862]])
```

5) Use `@` operator and verify outputs :

```
In [14]: (Solver @ b.T).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,2)
Out[14]: 
array([[-0.42715738, -2.61465808],
       [ 2.61465808, -0.42715738],
       [-1.35686862, -0.63436296],
       [ 0.63436296, -1.35686862]])
```

6) Use `tensordot` and verify outputs :

```
In [15]: np.tensordot(b, Solver, axes=((-1),(-1))).reshape(-1,2)
Out[15]: 
array([[-0.42715738, -2.61465808],
       [ 2.61465808, -0.42715738],
       [-1.35686862, -0.63436296],
       [ 0.63436296, -1.35686862]])
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [123]: ws = np.random.randint(1,9,(10000))

In [124]: x = np.random.randint(1,9,(10000))

In [125]: v = x
     ...: t0 = 10.0
     ...: Solver = np.array(((+np.cos(ws*t0), -np.sin(ws*t0)), \
     ...:                     (np.sin(ws*t0), +np.cos(ws*t0))))
     ...: b = np.vstack((x,v/ws))
     ...: 

In [126]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lk->lij',Solver, b).reshape(-1,2)
     ...: %timeit np.matmul(Solver, b.T).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,2)
     ...: %timeit np.tensordot(b, Solver, axes=((-1),(-1))).reshape(-1,2)
     ...: %timeit b.dot(Solver.reshape(4,-1).T).reshape(-1,2)
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 147 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.1 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 60 µs per loop
```

---

### Interpretation #2

Assumption : We have something like this -

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    v = x    
    w = ws[i]
    solver = np.array(((+np.cos(w*t0), -np.sin(w*t0)),
                        (+np.sin(w*t0), +np.cos(w*t0))))
    p = np.array((x[i], v[i]/w))
    p0 = np.matmul(solver, p) # output at each iteration
```

One way that would avoid any stacking operation and directly use the `sine`, `cosine` terms would be like so -

```
W = ws*t0
cS = np.cos(W)
sS = np.sin(W)
vws = v/ws
out = np.array((cS*x - sS*vws, sS*x + cS*vws))
```

Comment: Curious, according to your interpretation, even in the test case he wants a (4,2) result, while I think he wants a (2,10000) result.

Comment: @hpaulj You might be right about it. So, added other solution for such a case.